# Azure Deploy Failed, Kudu log inaccessible

Tags: azure, logging, deployment, kudu

I'm trying to deploy my app through Azure.
When I (re)deploy though Deployment Center the following activity is registered:

a) Updating submodules.

b) Preparing deployment for commit id 'xxxxx'

c) Generating deployment script.

d) Running deployment command...

Up until d) everything seems to go smooth, but deployment-status shows Failed. I get no error in the deployment center output. Last line is:

```
Using shared compilation with compiler from directory: D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild-16.8.0\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn
```

If I go check the D:\home\logFiles\kudu\trace folder and check the xml-logs, I see 2xx StatusCodes for GET_api_deployments_temp and for POST_deploy.
I cannot open the next log entry, Background_POST-deploy_pending, all I get is an error:

```
error on line 17 at column 181: Couldn't find end of Start Tag step
```

The file GET_api-deployments-temp returns again in the logs, only this time giving back a 404.

Xml-tags are indeed screwed. Can I correct this myself? Or am I causing this error myself? Are these the only logs I have access to? Seems like not much of a help.
I'm very new to this environment ànd to deploying and don't know how to tackle this or investigate further. Official documentation is severly lacking, and the issues on their gitHub don't provide me with solution.

Anyone got some tricks I can pull? All pointers are welcome!